# Is it possible to cut off the limbs of an enemy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am aware that vorpal weapons can instakill with a successful crit, but I am looking for something less drastic. Are there any feats, class features or rules that would allow cutting off the limbs of your enemy or damaging the muscles and tendons to make them unusable?

3rd party sources are allowed.

Comment: Are you looking just for disarming attacks generally, or cutting ones specifically? Is this a general question, or are you looking to replace/modify the vorpal trait?

Comment: Can you explain how this question is fundamentally different from [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33401/8610)? Or maybe even [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89476/8610)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I am not specifying the target creature and I am willing to use 3rd party materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are no official rules in D&D 3.5 for dismemberment in combat.

There are specific cases where it can happen (like the Vorpal weapon property mentioned in the question, the Wu Jen spell Decapitating Scarf (Complete Arcane p. 102), or the removal of a character's hand to make room for the [Hand of Vecna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_of_Vecna)), some of which provide rules for their specific case.

There's also a variant rule described on p. 27 of the DMG called "Damage to Specific Areas," but it doesn't really cover how dismemberment would work, it just suggests penalties to apply if a character, say, steps on a caltrop, or has their fingers slashed by a trap.

Since you mention being okay with third-party solutions, you might consider:

- [Torn Asunder: Critical Hits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982817517), a third-party Pathfinder supplement that provides detailed rules for dismemberment and other specific injuries that can happen in combat.
- The homebrew [Severing Limbs in combat](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?158843-Severing-Limbs-in-combat-3-5-D-amp-D) rules by *Omegas* for dismemberment.
- Coming up with your own homebrew rules, possibly drawing inspiration from any or all of the above.

Comment: That's weird since a number of monsters with regeneration special quality are mentioned to be able to put their chopped limbs back. They should provide players with some ways to chop those limbs first.

Answer (score -2):

The 2nd edition (and I believe 3.0) sword of sharpness was like a vorpal weapon except it delimbed people instead of decapitating them on a natural... 18-20?

Comment: I recommend verifying this with your available sources so that you can confidently say this does exist in D&D 3e and what it does in that edition.